# Point of Collision Between Two Particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

Two positions of two particles can be modelled by the vector equations; $$  r_1(t)=\begin{pmatrix} t-1\\t^2-1\end{pmatrix} $$ $$ r_2(t)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{-t}-1\\ e^{-2t}-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the coordinates of the point where the particles collide.

Just reading this question I was confused because previously in the question it was proven that both particles follow the curve $y=x^2+2x$ I thought there would be infinite points on collision. When solving the system of equations that come from $r_1(t) = r_2(t)$ I got to $0=0$ which means infinite solutions? I'm unsure because the textbook I'm working from got a single point which was $(-0.43,-0.68)$.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got $0=0$ when you wrote 2 separate eq-s, and they appeared to be identical, right? But that only means that collision *happens*, i. e. when $x_1  = x_2$ => $y_1 = y_2$. You still need to find these values. Solve any of those equations (as I said, they are identical) and you get the answer. BTW, there is no analytical solution.  The answer is given in special functions, specifically Lambert W function.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I think when I see this problem is "coordinate transformation". In particular, the translation:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x'\\y'\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then:

$$  r'_1(t)=\begin{pmatrix} t\\t^2\end{pmatrix} $$ $$ r'_2(t)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{-t}\\ [e^{-t}]^2\end{pmatrix}$$

so the fact that:

$$y'=x'^2$$

for both trajectories is trivial, and the solution reduces to one dimension, requiring:

$$t= e^{-t}$$

That is a famous equation, solved with the Lambert $W$-function.

Answer (score 0):

At the point of intersection, $x_1 = x_2$  which gives: t - 1 = $e^{-t}$ - 1.  Using Newton's method  this gives t = 0.5671.  You can put this into either of your vector equations to get (x,y).